# BASH order strings by the last "fields" (after "/" symbol")

Tags: string, bash

I'm looking for a method to sort line alphabetically by their last "field".
So:

if my output is (maybe by a grep command):

```
mike/downloads.png
mike/public/system.png
mike/root/alphabet.png
```

the result should be:

```
root/alphabet.png
downloads.png
public/system.png
```

beacuse "alphabet" , "downloads" and "system" are order alphabetically.

should I firts cut and sort them with " cut -f2 -d"/" | sort " ? and then merge the rest of the path?

or there is an easier way?

Any helps will be appreciated.

Thanks

(example modified)

Comment: Will last field always be at position # 3 ?

Comment: no unfortunately, last field should be also at position #2 or #4.

Comment: Hmm in that case all these answer won't work for you :(

Answer (score 4):

Sort has a `-t` parameter to specify the field delimiter, and `-k` to specify the field to sort on so you can write:

```
sort -t/ -k 3
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar for this great advice. But could happen that the output got less or much more deeper paths. And so I can't decide what field sort. I wish sort always the last field i. e. the name of the file (my first and unique example was so bad, sorry.)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all! I have finally found what i was looking for

first

```
awk -F'/' '{print $NF,$0}'
```

then

```
sort
```

and finally

```
sed -n 's/[^/]*\///p'
```

and the output will be

```
folder/file.png
file.png
folder/folder2/file.png
```

Comment: mark it as approved answer. could you explain what the `sed`-line does?

Answer (score 0):

This specifies the third field with a field delimiter of `/`

```
sort -t'/' -k 3
```

Answer (score 0):

As the number of fields is dynamic you could append the last field to the start of the line before sorting and remove it after:

```
$ awk -F'/' '{print $NF,$0}' file | sort | awk '{print $2}'
mike/root/alphabet.png
mike/downloads.png
mike/public/system.png
```